# Style ordered list adjacent to any heading with specific content with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, find

I've got a bunch of blog posts on a website I'm creating but unfortunately I'm unable to apply custom CSS to the blog posts or add classes to anything on the page.

How can I use JavaScript or jQuery apply CSS styles to any ordered list on the page wherever `<h3>Your checklist.</h3>` precedes it?

```
<h3>Your checklist.</h3>
<ol>
  <li>Tip</li>
  <li>Tip</li>
  <li>Tip</li>
  <li>Tip</li>
</ol>
```

I'd like other ordered and unordered lists on the page to use standard formatting. Only where the H3 of 'Your Checklist' precedes it do I want them styled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this, eg. with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h3").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "Your checklist.") {
            var list = $(this).next("ol");
            // code to change styles or add classes to "list" goes here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. How can I add a class to any of those ordered lists? I tried this but it didn't work.

<script>
$("h3").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Your checklist.") {
        var list = $(this).children("ol");
        .addClass('special-list-style');
    }
});
</script>

Comment: You need `list.addClass('special-list-style');` in that case

Comment: oh and if this is your only script (which I hadn't realised), then it should be within a`$(document).ready` callback. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried this but the class isn't getting added, it is detecting all of the checklists though. Here's my broken example? https://codepen.io/cbg/pen/EdZeaE

Comment: hi @cbg - apologies, I made a mistake in my jQuery, based on misreading your HTML. (My misreading made no sense at all, so there's no excuse for it!) I've since edited my aswer - it should have `.next("ol")` instead of `.children("ol")` (For some reason, don't ask me why, I thought the `ol` was a child of the `h3`, but it's not, it's the next sibling

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your help. I've updated my working example at https://codepen.io/cbg/pen/EdZeaE, very nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```js
$(function() {
  $("h3:contains(Your checklist.)").next("ol").addClass("special");
});
```

```css
ol {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ol.special {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Skipped</li>
</ol>
<h3>Your checklist.</h3>
<ol>
  <li>Tip</li>
  <li>Tip</li>
  <li>Tip</li>
  <li>Tip</li>
</ol>
<h3>Another Heading</h3>
<ol>
  <li>Skipped</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This would work well in some instances but doesn't work if the user created other ordered lists in the blog posts that they didn't want to be checklists.The idea of targeting the content of the H3 is so that a special checklist style is only created if it is actually a checklist. Thanks!

Comment: It now checks the content of h3. Ideally you should add something to that heading that could be targeted by CSS (a class, an id) and you won't need jQuery at all.